# Is that possible to call OnNavigatedFrom inside of any function?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have doubt that is it possible to call this inside the function.

```
OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs)
{
   base.OnNavigatingFrom()
}
```

Because, in my game, by clicking one button will navigate `newpage.xaml` (In this xaml I get the details of Purchase with Purchase Button)
By clicking the Purchase button inside the newpage.xaml needs to navigate to Purchase page of my game.

But, I don't know how to navigate from xaml page to my game.

**Note:** By pressing back button will get the previous page of my game. But, I need that action to be done only when i presses the Purchase Button.

Comment: did my answer help you, if so please mark as accepted

Answer (score 2):

Hello regarding the backkey you can simply override the command so as to catch the event and execute your code:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Teminate?","Do you want to exit the app.",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

        if (dialogResult == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            Application.Current.Terminate();
        }
        else if (dialogResult == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

And for navigation you have to use navigation service:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Chatting.xaml, UriKind.Relative));
```